# square-connect for react native available?

Tags: react-native, expo, square-connect

I'm working on a react native project and I would like to integrate the square API for the usage of micro payments. I looked into the square documentation and provided examples (https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples).

Apparently native mobile development is not support for the Transactions API + Payment Form or the Checkout API yet (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/take-payments). The Point of Sale API seems not to fit our needs.

Is there any way to get square-connect working for react native?

Thanks.

Comment: I built [`react-native-square-pos`](https://matix.io/react-native-square-pos/) to make it easier to interact with Square Point of Sale from React Native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be Square? There are a ton of other ways to take payments through react native.

1. [Apple & Android Pay (recommended)](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments)
2. [Stripe](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-stripe-api)
3. [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/)
4. [PayPal](https://github.com/hieudole/react-native-paypal-integration)

If it must be square via their Transactions API, then you should be able to get that done using WebView, in which case you'd probably want to also use one of these WebView communication libraries.

> NOTE: There are others

- https://github.com/R1ZZU/react-native-webview-messaging
- https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-advanced-webview

Comment: Hey Chris, Yes we prefer to use square because our app will do transactions under $10 (micro payments). We looked into other payment providers, including this you mentioned. But the pricing of all of them are a little bit over the edge. Square has the best pricing for micro payments. I tried to use WebView for react native but I need to create a square payment form object. But the code provided by square is only working in a browser, not in react native.

Comment: Cool - I think you'll have to go with the webview solution then. Will that work for you?

Comment: Sorry. I edited my previous answer. I tried to use WebView for react native but I need to create a square payment form object. But the code provided by square seems to work only in a browser. I can't import it into react native.

Comment: Within load any webpage within your webview, including your own with dom-based square payment form. You can communicate meta data to your web form (price, quantity, product, etc) using the webview messaging libraries I mentioned above. And you can communicate results (success, fail, etc) messages back from the webview to your native app. It should work for you.

Comment: Yes I looked into the libraries you mentioned and checked their documentation. It could work. I will give it a shot. Thanks for that!

Comment: Also check this out. They do linkedin authentication using a webview and a modal. Might be a clue or two in there for you. https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-linkedin

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will have a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

This project is pretty new and seems to be promising: https://github.com/SudoPlz/react-native-sp-reader-sdk. It aims to bridge the new Square ReaderSDK for react-native so you can take payments on your apps with the physical square devices.